# Delete button on UITableView overlays my UITableViewCell buttons

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with several labels and 3 buttons to the very right.  I used the prototype cell in Storyboard.  Display is fine but when I swipe to delete row in table the delete button displays on top of the cell content.  I have tried 2 things already.  One thing I am wondering, why isn't the contentView available at design time in Storyboard prototype cell?

Various autoresizingMask UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

controls are added to the contentView as 
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.buttonView];

my code in custom cell was initially empty just IBOutlets in the h file and the autogenerated m file which I didn't add anything but I now tried following and it doesn't make any difference

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize controls
        self.accountName.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.accountId.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.offerName.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.offerCode.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.createdDate.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.createdUser.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.orderValue.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.buttonInfo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.buttonEdit.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        self.buttonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

        // Add controls to Content View
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.accountName];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.accountId];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.offerName];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.offerCode];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.createdDate];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.createdUser];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.orderValue];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.buttonInfo];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.buttonEdit];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.buttonView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

my code in tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SavedOrderCell";

    if ([self.orders count] == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        SavedOrderCell *cell = (SavedOrderCell*)[tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.parentVC = self;

        [cell.buttonEdit addTarget: self action: @selector(editProduct:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // Configure the cell.
        Order *order = (Order *)[self.orders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.accountName.text = order.orderAccount.name;
        cell.accountId.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %i", [order.orderAccount.accountId intValue]];
        cell.offerName.text = order.orderPromotion.name;
        cell.offerCode.text = order.orderPromotion.code;
        cell.createdDate.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:order.createdDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        cell.createdUser.text = order.createdUser;
        cell.orderValue.text = [Common getCurrencyFormattedStringFromNumber:order.orderTotal];

//        [cell.buttonStatus setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status_%i", [order.statusId intValue]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.backgroundView.frame];
        bgImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        bgImage.opaque = NO;

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            bgImage.init.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_1col_mid_top.png"];
        else
        {
            if (indexPath.row % 2) {
                bgImage.init.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_1col_light.png"];
            }
            else{
                bgImage.init.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_1col_mid.png"];
            }
        }

        cell.backgroundView = bgImage;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is that tableview in xib?? In that case you have to set the autosize properties.. so that it will not overlap.set autosize top,bottom,right and left properties are there in the image given in xib inspector for autosize.

Comment: Yes table is in a storyboard.  Where are the autosize properties? I cannot find them.  I am using xCode 4.6

Comment: in the xib properties reset use autolayout property.so it will display the autosize properties.autolayout is first tab and inspector is 4th one i think

Comment: I don't want to disable all auto layout and autoresize is only available without auto layout.  I changed autoresizing then re enabled  autolayout but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing your UI programmatically make sure that

1. All of your cell's subviews are added to the contentView
2. All constraints are linked to contentView (not the cell itself)